# Merging on calculated value

Tags: r, join, data.table

Consider the following datasets:

```
left <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = c("foo", "bar", "bar"))
right <- data.table(c = c(1, 4), d = c("foo", "bar"))
```

Let's say that I want to join `left` and `right` based on the shared index `(a == 1; c == 1)`.

The output would look like this:

```
joined <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = c("foo", "bar", "bar"), d = c("foo", "bar", "bar"))
```

In SQL, you can JOIN tables using calculated fields without declaring them as separate values:

```
SELECT * FROM left INNER JOIN right ON (left.a = 1) = (right.c = 1)
```

Is there an R/data.table way to perform a similar function?

Comment: The logic of this join is not clear to me but you can use the same sql query using `sqldf` package in R.

Comment: may i ask which sql is that? `SELECT * FROM left INNER JOIN right ON (left.a = 1) = (right.c = 1)`. i know at least it does not work in TSQL.

Comment: Maybe I should have tested it in advance, but I know that MySQL allows for any expression that returns `TRUE` as its merge condition.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL is ok, as verified by:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT * FROM left INNER JOIN right ON (left.a = 1) = (right.c = 1)")
  a   b c   d
1 1 foo 1 foo
2 2 bar 4 bar
3 3 bar 4 bar
```

If you want to use **dplyr**, then the following gives the same result:

```
library(dplyr)
left %>%
   mutate(a1=a==1) %>%
   left_join(mutate(right, c1=c==1), 
            by=c("a1"="c1")) %>%
   select(-a1)
  a   b c   d
1 1 foo 1 foo
2 2 bar 4 bar
3 3 bar 4 bar
```